# Copy multiple files to FTP parallely with ant?

Tags: ant, ftp

i have to copy a large file via FTP.
For faster upload i have split the file into 10 parts and I'm trying to upload the splits using the 
target of ant.However i found that all the splits are queued and are not uploaded parallelly.  Does ant have any option to initiate parallel uploads ? For.eg in Filezilla you can have set the max parallel
upload limit to 10, which starts all the uploads parallelly  ?

Comment: Somewhat OT: Are you sure transferring ten files is faster than transferring one file of the same total size?

Comment: @Biffen I'm not sure how it works with ANT.I have observed this in FileZilla that a single file does not make the best use of my good enough internet bandwidth.For eg a single file gets transferred at 100Kbps , however if i initiate upload for all 10 files , they all get transferred at 100Kbps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your tasks in the `<parallel>` task. When your build file looks similar to

```
<ftp ...transfer split1 />
<ftp ...transfer split2/>
...
<ftp ...transfer split10/>
```

just put these targets in a `parallel` element:

```
<parallel>
  <ftp ...transfer split1 />
  <ftp ...transfer split2/>
  ...
  <ftp ...transfer split10/>
</parallel>
```

In case you may want to limit the number of parallel tasks (i.e. file transfers) you can set the `threadCount` property, e. g.

```
<parallel threadCount="4">
```

lets a maximum of 4 threads run in parallel.

If you need to handle several tasks after each other, e.g. transfering a file and then logging that the file was transferred, you can cluster those tasks in a `<sequential>` task:

```
<parallel>
  <sequential>
    <ftp ...transfer split1 />
    <echo>transferred file 1</echo>
  </sequential>
  <sequential>
    <ftp ...transfer split2/>
    echo>transferred file 2</echo>
    ...
  </parallel>
```